# crystal report in only one page

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2008, crystal-reports

I want to print a receipt of supermarket I designed it :
section 1 header 
section 2 the head of table 
section 3 the table 
section 4 report footer section 1 has the total bill

if number of rows more than 40 it print the report footer in new page with new head of table and new empty table

I want to print the report footer at the end of the table and doesn't depend on number of rows in table how?

Comment: Do you have a fixed page size? Is this report going to be printed, exported, or viewed online/in an app?

Answer (score 0):

You're basically asking if Crystal Reports can print an unlimited amount of records on a single page. The answer is no.

To get around your issue, I guess you could dynamically reduce the font size the more records you have in the report, but this would not handle "unlimited" rows.

Other than that, you may have a "paper size" issue. You can address that in your printer setup.